# Silverstripe fields validation in CMS

Tags: php, validation, content-management-system, silverstripe

Note: version 3.1

[image]

Trying to validate the input of this fields from CMS:

- expiry date must be after publish date.

I tried even a simple validation (required) but doesn't work.

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
    $publishDatetimeField = new DatetimeField( 'PublishDate', 'Publish Date'   );
    $expiryDatetimeField = new DatetimeField( 'ExpiryDate', 'Expiry Date' );
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Options', $publishDatetimeField);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Options', $expiryDatetimeField);
}
public function getCMSValidator(){
    return new RequiredFields('publishDatetimeField');
}
```

I can manipulate the values and compare them, but i can't access them.

Any ideas, are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the basic validator in terms of checking a field isn't blank... but you should be using the name of the field "PublishDate", not "publishDatetimeField".

In general this is how validations are fully set in silverstripe...

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {

    static $db = array(
        'MyDateField'       => 'SS_DateTime',
    );

    function getCMSValidator() {
        return new MyDataObject_Validator();
    }
}

class MyDataObject_Validator extends RequiredFields {

    function php($data) {
        $bRet = parent::php($data);

        //do checking here
        if (empty($data['MyDateField']))
            $this->validationError('MyDateField','MyDateField cannot be empty','required');

        return count($this->getErrors());
    }
}
```

you can check for what the data...

```
die(var_dump($data));
```

and this should be a string in MYSQL format... like "2016-03-24 11:41:00"